# How do you study tutorial character control with Ogre3D and Bullet physics

Tags: bulletphysics, ogre3d

english is not my native language, so sorry for that

I try to use Bullet Physics at `Ogre3D` for character moving.
but I have no idea what is sample about character moving in `BulletPhysics`,
if anybody know some simple tutorial source, or simple sample source about Character Moving by `BulletPhysics` and `Ogre3D`, please tell me , thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is game specific. Every game has it's own needs and there is no way one type of CC could suit every game so
consider this [tutorial](http://codefreax.org/tutorials/view/id/3) and [example](http://bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/)

Comment: Yeah i totally agree your opinion. I already read that tutorial, but thanks to your help :) have a nice day